# Enzyme: How could I mock a function that passing as props

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, antd

I'm writing a testing with Enzyme but do not know how to mock a function that passing as props.

```
it("should do not login when submit a user that not exist", () => {
        const mock = jest.fn(() => true);
        const wrapper = shallow(<HomeFormComponent form={{getFieldDecorator: () => mock()}}/>);
        wrapper.find(Form).simulate("submit", {
            preventDefault: () => {},
        });
        console.log(wrapper)
    });
```

An error.

```
TypeError: getFieldDecorator(...) is not a function
```

In my index.js

```
      render() {
      const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
      }
      return (<FormItemContainer>
            {getFieldDecorator("password", {
              rules: [
                { required: true, message: "Please input your Password!" }
              ]
            })(
              <Input
                prefix={
                  <Icon type="lock" style={{ color: "rgba(0,0,0,.25)" }} />
                }
                type="password"
                placeholder="Password"
              />
            )}
          </FormItemContainer>)
```

Comment: you've an extra curly brace after `const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
      }`

Comment: Have you tried passing ``form={{getFieldDecorator: mock}}`` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

will this work?

```
const mock = jest.fn();
const wrapper = shallow(<HomeFormComponent form={{getFieldDecorator: mock}}/>);
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.